# Unicode characters for font awesome 'search' not showing up after upgrading Font Awesome

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-awesome-5, fontawesome-4.4.0

I was using font awesomes 'search' font

```
<i class="fas fa-search"></i>
```

unicode characters

> f002

in my search field placeholder like this

```
<input id="navbarSearchField" type="text" class="form-control searchInputsHeight" style="font-family:Arial, FontAwesome" placeholder="&#xf002;  Location" aria-describedby="navbarDate" />
```

and it was working fine until I upgraded to Font Awesome 5.0.13 from the older  4.4

Looking at the Font Awesome [site](https://fontawesome.com/icons/search?style=solid) the unicode characters are still the same.

So I'm wondering if there is some file I missed when downloading the fonts or am I not implementing it correctly?

Comment: Try using `font-family:Font Awesome 5 Free`, they use different font-family name in version 5

Comment: I tried 'Font Awesome 5 Free' and 'FontAwesome 5 Free' with no luck. Are you sure this is the new way to show it?

Comment: Couldyou post your full html code with link to fontawesome css file. that would help

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a very interesting question, and I'm sure this is not a 100% perfect solution, but I found [this Github Issue](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/11946), where they say, that you also need to set `font-weight: 900` for solid Font Awesome Icons. Also the `font-family` changed a bit, as mentioned in the comments. Please take a look at the snippet below, I am not sure if you can "unbold" the text after the icon.

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input id="navbarSearchField" 
       type="text" 
       class="form-control searchInputsHeight" 
       style="font-family: Arial, Font Awesome\ 5 Free; font-weight: 900;" 
       placeholder="&#xf002 Location" 
       aria-describedby="navbarDate" 
/>
```

It seems like you would'nt need to set a specific font-weight with the "Regular" Icon Pack of FA, but unfortunaly this is part of FA Pro, which you would have to purchase.

Comment: Just FYI - in the debugger window I see a line through the style property with a info icon that says "Invalid property value". Not sure why, even though it shows the icon!

Comment: @user1186050 Weird, I don't see this (Chrome 66). What browser are you using? Is the complete style attribute striked out?

Comment: yes and I'm using the latest version of Chrome (66)

Comment: It is strange, but I cannot reproduce this

Comment: On my computer (and I presume all computers where Arial contains a glyph for F002), this snippet shows ﬁ rather than the FA icon. You're right about the 900 weight though, so it's possible to do what the OP wants by only giving the placeholder the font. See also http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/mopn054k/1/

Answer (score 2):

```html
<input id="navbarSearchField" class="fas" type="text" placeholder="&#xf002;  Location" aria-describedby="navbarDate" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-DNOHZ68U8hZfKXOrtjWvjxusGo9WQnrNx2sqG0tfsghAvtVlRW3tvkXWZh58N9jp" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Just add class `fa` or `fas` to the input:

```
<input id="navbarSearchField" class="fa" type="text" placeholder="&#xf002;  Location" aria-describedby="navbarDate" />
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/3601/

Comment: It looks like this worked, but it changed the font inside the search field. Do you know why it changed. I also used 'font-family:Arial, FontAwesome 5 Free;'

Comment: @user1186050 The font inside changed because class fa uses Font Awesome font family.

Comment: is there a way to use/set my original font-family?

Comment: You can change the font of the placeholder alone by writing `input::placeholder {font:900 1em 'Font Awesome 5 Free';}` and then you won't need to change the stye of the input itself. See http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/mopn054k/1/

Comment: I'm getting an error that says ::placeholder is not a valid CSS 3.0 pseudo-element. Additionally, if I run your example and I change the fon-family then the icon disappears

Comment: Where do you get this error? The W3C CSS validator doesn't complain. And what are you changing the font-family to? My example works fine, under various browsers and OSes.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. Here is what I did.

```
<input id="navbarSearchField" type="text" class="form-control searchInputsHeight" style="font-family:Arial, 'Font Awesome 5 Free'; font-weight: 600; color: #777; font-size: 20px;" placeholder="&#xf002;  Location" aria-describedby="navbarDate" />
```

Notice the single quotes around the font-family 'Font Awesome 5 Free'. If I did't use the single quotes it worked with a class 'fa' used but used the Font Awesome font family, now it uses my font. 'Circular' without the fa class being used.
Additionally I had to add font-weight: 600 or it wouldn't show up! The font-weight is explained in the FA documents online